# I want to print two entries into a table on a webpage from Mysql and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

****I want the entries to appear as such:****

```
Entry 1 Entry 2
```

****I thought by adding an extra line in fetch.php:****

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  array_push($result, array('brand' => $row[0]));
  array_push($result, array('brand' => $row[1]));
}   
echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
```

****Then an extra line in the javascript:****

```
$.each(result.result, function() {
  $('#AllBooks').append('<tr><td>' + this['brand'] + '</td>');
  $('#AllBooks').append('<td>' + this['brand'] + '</td></tr>');
});
```

**But this doesn't work.  Any suggestions?**

Comment: You can't append partial elements, ie. `<tr>` in one `append()` and `</tr>` in another. You need to create the entire `<tr>` element in a single action

Answer (score 0):

Try This and check

```
$.each(result, function(key, res) {

$('#AllBooks').append('<tr><td>' + res.brand + '</td></tr>');

});
```

Comment: Sadly not.  It comes out as 'undefined'. Perhaps there is a completely different way to do this?

Comment: but if I put 'result.result',  e.g. '$.each(result.result, function(key, res) ' then I get the same results as before - just Entry 1